# Fail to install ImpalaODBC

Tags: ubuntu, odbc, impala

I'am trying to install ImpalaODBC on an Ubuntu server. Here is the history:

```
sudo apt-get install unixodbc //success
sudo apt-get install libsasl2-modules-gssapi-mit //success
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/cloudera/impalaodbc/lib/64:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
export ODBCSYSINI=/path/to/impala-php/odbc
export ODBCINI=/path/to/impala-php/odbc/odbc.ini
export SIMBAINI=/path/to/impala-php/odbc/cloudera.impalaodbc.ini
export LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libodbcinst.so.1
```

However, I got an error:

```
[01000][unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib '/opt/cloudera/impalaodbc/lib/64/libclouderaimpalaodbc64.so' : file not found
```

Then, I check the /opt. It's empty! How to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by my self.
Just run the follow command:

```
sudo dpkg -i clouderaimpalaodbc_2.5.29.1009-2_amd64.deb
```